# Communication between parent and child activities in android

Tags: android

I have an Activity A that start a new activity B by using startActivityForResult(). Activity B has a custom view which also contains a textView T. Now, Activity A needs to send a String to update the textView T which is in Activity B. What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intent putExtra method to send string like this.

```
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
    mIntent.putExtra(key, value);
       StartActivity (activity2);
```

and in activity B recieve it like this

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

In activity A.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("string_textview", YourString);
startActivity(ii);
```

In activity B.

```
String text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("string_textview");
textview.setText(text);
```

Hope it helps (:

Comment: I tried this and I get null pointer exception for the last line:

`View view1 = mView.getView();
setContentView(view1);
testView = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.testDataView);
String datafromActivity = getIntent().getExtras().getString("string_textview");
testView.setText(datafromActivity);`

Comment: Why are you using get view?, the text view is not getting asigned because of the view 1, delete that

Answer (score 0):

to pass data between 2 activitys use Bundles

```
Intent startActivitB = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("new_text", "Abcdefg");

startActivivitB.putExtras(b);
startAcitvity(startAcivitytB);
```

And on the Activity B get the Bundle:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String new_text = b.getString("new_text");
```

And then you can update the textview

```
textview.setText(new_text);
```